# Socket.io add listeners in Express 4 routes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I declare socket server in separate module. I have access to the object of the server everywhere in application, for example I can emmit. But I can't add listener in the route, for example:

```
router.post('/example', function(req, res, next) {
  var socketio = req.app.get('sock');

  socketio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function (text) {
        console.log('ok');
    });
});
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: First off, it really makes no sense to put this code inside a route handler.  A route handler is something that is triggered when any single client hits a route.  Your socket.io listeners need to apply to all clients and not depend upon the behavior of one client.  If you can back up and describe what higher level problem you're really trying to solve here, we can probably suggest a much better approach.

Comment: I'm trying to create the scheme: client send request via http(my post route), then server send socket request to some device, then server recieve data from device and send any result to client via http.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow what you're trying to do.  In an http request, you would typically just return the results of that request back as the response to the http request.  Why is a socket.io connection involved in an http request at all?  You still haven't explained why you need to do anything with socket.io in this specific http request.

Comment: Socket.io connection involved in an http request because I should send socket message to some device and receive data from it just when client send post ajax request to /example route.

Comment: That's easy.  You just need to do a `deviceSocket.emit()` to the device you want to send to.  That raises the question about what device you are trying to send to and where you have stored that particular `socket` object so you can do `deviceSocket.emit()`.  You haven't shared anything about that so I don't know how we could help you there.  What socket is it that you want to send data to?  Did it previously connect to your server?

Comment: For example, my computer can be like this device. I starts script:<br/>                           var io = require('socket.io-client');<br/>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');<br/>

    socket.on('message', function () {<br/>
  socket.emit('example', {message: });<br/>
    }); <br/>                                                                                                                        then I send to this client message from express route and want to catch event 'example'.

Comment: Multi-line code is not readable in comments.  If you need to explain your question better, then put the multi-line code in your actual question by using the "edit" link and then post a comment advising us that you have updated your question to make it clearer.

Comment: A server is available for lots of clients to use.  If you want to send a socket.io message to one specific client when this route is hit, you need to be able to know somehow which client you are trying to send that message to and what its socket object is.

Comment: Client send only http requests, server use socket to communicate with some device. This device is single and is not client.

Comment: Is there some constraint forcing you to use this model? Why not just open up socket connections for the device and the client? No sense in waiting for an HTTP response when you already have a Websocket server running that can push data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If there is just a single device that you want to communicate with and it should have already connected to your server and `req.app.get('sock')` is how you get access to the `socketio` server object, then you can do it like this:

```
var theDeviceSocket;
req.app.get('sock').on('connection', function(socket) {
    theDeviceSocket = socket;
});

router.post('/example', function(req, res, next) {
    if (theDeviceSocket) {
        theDeviceSocket.emit("someMsg", "someData");
    }
    // send whatever response you want to send
    res.end();
});
```

---

If you were trying to get a response from the single device and return that as the response to the POST, then you could so something like this:

```
// store the one connection to/from the special device
var theDeviceSocket;

// keep a request cntr so we can tell which response goes with which request
var requestCntr = 0;

req.app.get('sock').on('connection', function(socket) {
    theDeviceSocket = socket;
});

router.post('/example', function(req, res, next) {
    var timer, thisRequestId;

    function gotData(data) {
        // if this is our specific response
        if (data.requestId === thisRequestId) {
            theDeviceSocket.removeListener("someMsgResponse", gotData);
            res.send(data);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }

    if (theDeviceSocket) {
        theDeviceSocket.on("someMsgResponse", gotData);
        thisRequestId = requestCntr++;
        theDeviceSocket.emit("someMsg", {requestId: thisRequestId});

        // set up a timeout in case we don't get the proper response
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            theDeviceSocket.removeListener("someMsgResponse", gotData);
            res.send("error");
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

This second scheme is complicated by the fact that you have architected this to be a request/response scheme, but socket.io is not a request/response protocol.  So, in order to know which response belongs to which request (when there are potentially multiple clients interacting with the server at the same time), you have to implement some sort of requestId in the data you send and receive over socket.io.  This means you have to change the device to echo back the requestId you sent it with its response.  All of this would not be necessary if you used a protocol that is designed for request/response like HTTP instead of socket.io.

Comment: There is no call to `res.send()`, so this wouldn't return anything to the client. This reveals a bigger issue with OP's model here .... the POST request triggers the emission of a message via Websocket, and then the server must wait for the device to respond with the data intended to return to the client. What if the device never responds? Furthermore, you would need the call to `res.send()` to be within the message handler for the socket, so it can actually access the data intended for the client.

Comment: @djfdev - I assumed the OP would send whatever response they needed to send.  Sorry, but I did not understand from the question that the POST request is supposed to wait for a response from the socket.io connection.  As you can likely already tell from all the back and forth, this question is not very clear so I'm trying to help the best I can with the unclear question.

Comment: @djfdev - I added more to my answer, but if the OP wants request/response from the single device, then socket.io is simply the wrong type of protocol for that.  They should probably just use http.  Or, if they are going to stick with socket.io, they'd have to number requests and responses so they can be properly associated together and other responses in flight at the same time can be ignored.

Comment: Nice, yeah I was thinking this too but then I realized also that it could cause your HTTP responses to get criss-crossed..

Comment: @djfdev - yeah, if this is really what the OP wants to do, then socket.io is the wrong protocol for request/response.  I've modified my answer again to show a requestId added to each socket.io message so one could identify which response belongs with which request if the server echoes back the id in it's response, but that's messy.  It would be better to use a request/response protocol like HTTP for talking to the device.